# Java 2D Platformer Gravity

Tags: java, game-physics

I am currently making a 2D Platformer in Java. I am a beginner so take it easy.
I have a problem with the gravity in the game. I am using different variables for falling and jumping. I am using a tiled map. So lets get to the point.
My fall method works like this -

```
if(collisionDown == false) {
    characterY += fall;
    fall ++;
{
```

fall is equal to 4. and If collisionDown is true it resets back to 4.

My jump method is almost the same:

```
if(key.E == true && collisionDown == true) {
   characterY -= jump;
   jump --;
}
```

jump is equal to 16. and If collisonDown is true it resets back to 16.

Now problem is: imagine the character is jumping. its in the air and while going down characterY += fall; lets say characterY = 250 and fall is equal - 15 at that exact moment. The next solid tile below the character starts at Y position  255. character is at 250 and does NOT detect collision so next frame it adds 15 to characterY which is 250 + 15 = 265. At that point the character has "entered" the solid tile which was at positionY 255.

I have "fixed" that so the character gets back ON TOP of the solid tile (and that is visible and annoying.) That is not the perfect solution because it slows the character 1 frame each time it enters a solid tile(which is because it detects left and right collision and the character can't move). The character visibly stutters if I can say it like that.

I need a solution for that problem but can't think of any.
So if you make a suggestion I would be happy. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably use something like the following.

```
if(collisionDown == false) {
    characterYnext = characterY + fall;          //Get Next Position
    if(NextMovementCollides()){                  //Basically if next position is too far. 
    characterYnext += difference_between(CharacterY,Ground);     //This should move the character to the ground state.
    fall = 0;                                                   //No longer falling so reset the value.
    }
    else{characterY += fall; fall++;}       //Otherwise continue falling like normal.
}
```

DISCLAIMER: I'm not a java programmer so my syntax might be a bit off.

This should work, just plug in your game logic where it would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

The way I usually handle this, is to pre-check movement:

```
private int moveDown(int fall){
        if (isSolidBlock(characterX, characterY + fall)){
            //Knowing the height of your block, calculate some kind of reduction. If your block height is 40, it's probably something like (characterY + fall)%40
            fall = 4;
            collisionDown = true;
            return maxFallUntilSolidBlockReached();
        }
        fall++;
        return fall;
    }

private boolean isSolidBlock(int x, int y){
        //Implement some kind of check if at (x,y) there's a solid block.
    }
```

Then just do this for the fall calculation:

```
if(collisionDown == false) {
            characterY += moveDown(fall);
        }
```

Comment: Hm. That seems like a reasonable idea, but I don't really understand the
 return maxFallUntilSolidBlockReached();

Comment: If you are using a grid, with all blocks having a static width en height, you know the y-coordinate of the block under you. Say your blocks have a height of 20 pixels and characterY+fall = 122. You can subtract 20 from the 122 until you have a number < 20, or simply use 122 mod 20. This results in 2, meaning you would fall 2 pixels too deep. To fix this simply reduce the characterY+fall by 2 and use that as your update! This is assuming you use a grid of course. If that's not the case there are other options, but I'd need to see your map implementation to really help you out then =)

Comment: Thanks for the help :D, but a guy suggested an easier solution which worked. Thanks anyway

Comment: No problem, although Esseh's solution is identical to mine. You still need to do those calculations ;)